# Odoo cannot print on server

Tags: odoo-15

I deployed my Odoo App on our own server.
When I tested it on my Local Computer, it was just working fine.
But when it deployed, it can't download a Report

The console throw error like this

Error on Console
[image]
The App shows a notification of Connection Lost and Reconnect

Any advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your configuration file. When you are working in your local with one worker, the longpolling is not enabled and it doesn't use. If you are going to use with port numbers on the url as the error suggests there are few things you need to check.

1. Check the conf file for correct ports. If there is no configuration file generate one and to the service with correct ports.
2. Check that the server ports are accessible from outside of your server. I'd suggest using NGINX and not exposing ports.
3. reports normally shouldn't go to the longpolling port if that is the case. So setting the `web.base.url` and `web.base.url.freeze` parameters in the settings, to avoid changes in the url when accessing from ports.